# Failed to get token

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to fetch some data into the cloud firestore database and when I do this I get this error `Failed to get token: com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: getToken aborted due to token change.`.

pubspec.yaml

```
cloud_firestore: ^0.9.7
firebase_auth: ^0.8.1+4
```

android/build.gradle:

```
 dependencies {
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'       
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
 }
```

Method that fetched the employee_information:

```
static addEmployee(Map<String, dynamic> snapshot){
  Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction tx) async{
   await tx.set(Firestore.instance.collection('employee').document(),snapshot);
    });
  }
```

If you've come across this issue let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

for ERROR [FirestoreCallCredentials]: Failed to get token:

1. go to https://console.cloud.google.com/ - select your project
2. Select API&Services
3. Select Credentials
4. and Update the values in API Keys